# java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an error while running my app, it keeps crashing and giving out this error.

> Process: com.ahmadtakkoush.source, PID: 29506
>
> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.username.appname/com.username.appname.MainActivity}:
> ```
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing
> transactions

Here's a code sample
https://pastebin.com/ufF5LsbU

Comment: Please post a chunk of the logcat error output to better understand the problem.

Comment: okay here is the logcat @srjhnd: https://pastebin.com/ujZyA6Az

Comment: Can you also add `HomeFragment` ?

Comment: home fragment @Md.Asaduzzaman: https://pastebin.com/V79hJczz

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())` from `addSnapshotListener` listener and use like below:

```
query.addSnapshotListener( new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() { 
    // implementation here
});
```

Handle the listener detachment with `listener.remove` on `onPause()`.

```
//Stop listening to changes
registration.remove();
```

See more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener)